# Create InputBox in Visual Studio Code using .NET Core console application

Tags: .net-core, console-application, inputbox

Is it possible to create InputBox in Visual Studio Code using .NET Core console application?
How can we do that?

Comment: since when does a console application have a window interface

Comment: It can be https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b626f2d9-0a77-4fee-bc51-04a863004dd6/c-inputbox-to-use-with-a-console-application?forum=csharpgeneral but there are problems in VisualStudioCode